# Activity fields referencing UI elements

Tags: android, android-layout

It would be "cheaper" to store reference to layout element rather than findViewById every time you need it, but wouldn't it prevent garbage collection? My assumption is that in onStop state views get destroyed, at least onSaveInstanceState is called. So, reference to a UI element in activity or fragment prevents the element from being collected - right ?

Am I wrong or should I stick to findViewById or try weakreferences ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way is to store the view reference in activity if it will be accessed multiple times.

Invoke findViewById everywhere makes code ugly i think.

I don't believe store the view reference will impact the gc, cause you can use Activity to access all ui element, their references are already held.

Comment: All it does have is `private Window mWindow`. I think you're wrong in your suggestion. Btw you can prove me wrong with MAT - don't have time for it atm, but I'm pretty it's essential for gc to retain objects due to strong links.

Comment: you're right, it have mWindow not the views. but i'm not sure what mWindows holds, since i never went through the android source code. but i still think it's a bad idea to invoke findViewById many times or use WeakReference. The activity itself holds many resources, why are you concern the view reference it holds? If you not leak the activity instance as http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html mentions, you won't get into memory trouble for just keeping view reference in activity.

Comment: because, I guess, views get destroyed in onStop state and restored in onStart - at least onSaveInstanceState is called, where view params(position, dimensions) need to be saved into a Parcelable.

Comment: well, i don't know about whether view will be destroyed in onStop or not. but all the android apps code i saw keep view reference in activity, and this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is : It depends,

If you are going to be referencing the UI repeatedly, It would be cheaper to save the references. It not, then you can just use findViewById a couple of times. In most apps under normal conditions, Either way wouldn't make much noticeable difference to performance as these tasks are not very system intensive.  So my final answer would be, Do whatever is most comfortable for you in your workflow since performance gains/losses are almost negligible (unless you do this a huge number of times of times).

Comment: but am I right about view retention due to activity references ? If so  I would rather do findView or some reference "nulling" when user leaves the current activity.

Comment: Yes you are. If you have a reference then it will be saved as long as Activity is on the stack. You can null them when you leave the activity in onPause() and reset them i onResume() when you return.

Comment: yep, that's what I meant. Let's see if anyone has something else to add.